# how to combine a variable and a special character into a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to do something like this:

```
st = 'abcdef'
wr = 'ab'

if re.search(^wr,st):    
    print 'OK'
```

the problem is I cannot combine special character with a variable (i.e. ^wr). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe all you need is `if re.match(wr,st):` since you want to match at the start of the string only?

Comment: Note that you want to combine the character with the **value** of the variable, not with the name of the variable. You can do this with the `+` operator which concatenates two string values.